# Why were EVM opcodes not made to be compatible with assembly?

Tags: evm

It seems like both machine language and the ethereum machine read through instructions like ADD or MOV or etc..

Why did Vitalik, when he made ethereum not just follow that standard, it seems quite similar and it has the same objectives.

What were the reasons to not share these opcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many moving parts to an actual CPU - memory virtualization, system interrupts, clocks, etc.

Ethereum being the first turing-complete blockchain aimed for simplicity.
the first question you want to ask choosing a CPU architecture is probably whether it is stack based (like EVM) or register based (like x86 or ARM), and for simplicity I guess stack based VM wins.

you also want to avoid DoS attacks, so memory access is just a like a single page and cost is exponential.